# Is there a way to automatically transfer data from aws report to google sheet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, automation

I get automated reports from aws server to my mail via a link. the aws link is similar to this (http://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/analytics/Company/Stock/MS_2020-08-03T02:43-9ebb780c.xlsx)  - data might be deleted now.

Is there a way where i can automatically load the excel file from this report on to google sheet

Also, i dont have access to S3 server. its maintained by a different firm and we get only auto reports.

Comment: Do a web search for [S3 to Google Sheet](https://www.google.com/search?q=s3+to+google+sheet&oq=s3+to+google+sheet)

Comment: The problem is i dont have access to S3. i get only the report link on daily basis